# VB6 IDE crashes adding component cwdaq.ocx

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 project that runs on WIN7 and tries to make it run on WIN10
But I have a problem adding components to its VB6

When I adding :

[image]

The result got:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Did the IDE ever recover from freezing up? Or would it stay like that forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cwdaq.ocx control is correctly registered it should be visible in the components window:

[image: cwdaq]

If not, try to re-register it as admin with regsvr32 utility.

Comment: I unregister and register again and now its look fine...